# Accessing SNS topic from other user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am assessing the security of an SNS topic and I noticed it has the following configuration:

```
{
    "Action": [
      "SNS:Receive",
      "SNS:Subscribe"
    ],
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:topicowner:topic",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Sid": "__console_sub_0"
}
```

I am not the topic owner, however, given the fact it allows for anonymous access (or at least authenticated access for any AWS account), I assumed I could subscribe to it with the following CLI command:

> aws sns subscribe --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:topicowner:topic" --protocol email --notification-endpoint my-email@example.com

(I configured it yusing my AWS access key and secret)

But I got the followingn error instead:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: TopicArn

Am I assuming wrong? Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topic arn does not seem a valid one, it is missing `AWS Account id`. Correct syntax is:

`arn:aws:sns:region:account-id:topicname`

Just for correction, when you say `given the fact it allows for anonymous access`. It is not true, `Principal` wildcard means all users within AWS account not any anonymous user.

Also try adding region ‘—region us-east-1’

Comment: I removed the original account-id from the post, but the one I used has the topic owner (not me) as the account-id. Also, I am using a valid AWS account (not inside the same account as the topic owner, though)

Comment: is another account in the same region? regardless try adding `--region us-east-1`

Comment: i’ve now mentioned region in my original answer. If it worked then please accept my answer :) thanks